# C++: Pass string literal as a string& leads to compilation failure, why

Tags: c++, string, char, constants, literals

I am using g++4.1.2 to compile this:

```
    cat 1.cpp
#include<iostream> 
#include<string> 
using namespace std; 
void f(const string& s){} 
void g(string& s){} 
void h(string s){} 
int main() 
{ 
    string s="abc"; 
    f("abc"); 
    g("abc”);//Error 
    h("abc"); 
    return 0; 
}
```

It failed at line “g();”

```
$ g++ 1.cpp 
1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’: 
    1.cpp:11: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘std::string&’ from a    temporary of type ‘const char*’ 
1.cpp:5: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void g(std::string&)’
```

I don’t quite understand that, as long as “abc” could be the constructor parameter for std::string:

> For f()，"abc" can be used to construct a string(const char*), as a const reference to string
>
> For h() “abc” can be used to construct a r-value, temporary std::string object.

For g()，why it cannot be used to construct a left-value reference string&, while const reference string& is OK?

Comment: You used a weird quote mark in the `g` call .. it should be `"`

Comment: In short, lvalue reference can't be bound to temporary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the language rules are designed this way. You can bind an rvalue to a const lvalue reference (and extend its lifetime to that of the reference), because it is explicitly allowed.

Assuming C++03 since you're using g++ 4.1.2

> § 8.5.3 [dcl.init.ref] / 5
>
> A reference to type “cv1T1” is initialized by an expression of type
>   “cv2T2” as follows:
>
> - If the initializer expression
>
>   - is an lvalue (but is not a bit-field), and “cv1T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2T2,” or
>   - has a class type (i.e.,T2is a class type) and can be implicitly converted to an lvalue of type [...]
> - Otherwise, *the reference shall be to a non-volatile const type* [...]
>
>   - If the initializer expression is an rvalue, withT2a class type, and “cv1T1” is reference-compatible with “cv2T2,” [...]
>   - Otherwise, a temporary of type “cv1T1” is created and initialized from the initializer expression using the rules for a non-reference
>       copy initialization (8.5).  *The reference is then bound to the
>       temporary.*